# I'm not able to access java application l have deployed on ubuntu server through browser

Tags: spring-boot, ubuntu, deployment

I have deployed a spring boot application on ubuntu server. Just a simple rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/v1")
public class RestTest {

    @GetMapping(value = "test")
    public String test() {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

My application.properties file

```
server.address=0.0.0.0
server.port=5050
```

The firewall is inactive so l suppose that there is no rule that preventing me from accessing this endpoint.
Also when l do telnet [Adress] [port]

```
Trying [adress]...
Connected to [adress]
Escape character is '^]'.
```

And on browser l get "took too long to respond."
I can ping the server, I can connect with ssh, so l really don't know what is not working properly.
Thanks in advance!